# if statement handling-manipulation

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, if-statement

well, ive been wondering if such thing is possible in python

```
while True:
    if True:
        x = -5
        x = 5
```

now i mean, whenever if statement is true,(in this example) the first time x to equal -5 and the second time is true, x to equal 5 ,and again the same

i know it sounds absurd but im trying to make a game which the ball has to go rightward and when returns leftward,and this thing over and over again

sorry for my bad english but it's really difficult for me to explain this

thanks in advance

Comment: No one writes that the way you're thinking, because there's too much that can go wrong. Use two discrete conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply negate x each time the condition is true

```
x = 5
while True:
    if True:
        x = -x
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to count the iterations of the while loop so like this. This will let you switch between each iteration of the loop. If you just want to make it switch positive negative do x=-x.

```
x=0

while True:
    if x%2==0:  #if x is even do
        y=5
    else:
        y=-5
    print y
    x+=1  #add 1 to x
    if x==10:   #quit at 10
        break
```